# Request for an ID of two spider species found in Australia, NT

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

These two spiders were found in the Northern Territory in Australia in July (winter time). Both arachnids were shot during the night (I suspect them to be **nocturnal**), and both were found close to the **ground**. They do not build webs I think (way too big).

The upper spider is quite **big**, pretty much hand-sized, and about as big as a bird-eating spider. I think the guy with us told us it was a species of **wolf spider** (if I recall correctly - I'm unsure). The bottom hairy spider with its nice camouflage is somewhat smaller (if I recall correctly), but still well sized.

I have been searching for their names, but the amount of spider species is overwhelming and Australians tend to focus online resources on the poisonous ones. I'm fairly sure these two are harmless.

[image: spider1][image: spider2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom one is most certainly a Huntsman. Something akin to a *Holconia immanis*, aka the Sydney Huntsman. The picture is difficult but a characteristic Huntsman typically has 2 front legs that are longer than the back legs. And of course they tend to be larger spiders.

[image: Huntsman]
 <sup>*Holconia immanis*. source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holconia_immanis)</sup>

The top one looks like a type of brushed trapdoor spider (family *Barychelidae*), typically composed of such species as *Idiommata scintillans*, which are known as silverbacks or goldbacks depending on the color of the hair on their head ([ref](https://ednieuw.home.xs4all.nl/australian/Mygalomorphae/Mygalomorphae.htm)).

[image: Trapdoor Spider]
<sup>*Idiommata sp*., the 'Silverback'. source: [Archne.org.au](http://www.arachne.org.au/01_cms/details.asp?ID=2611)</sup>

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add some sources and pictures. Please feel free to undo. Thanks!!!